# How far can one nest rows and columns before breaking the bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Good day,

I am a newbie to web designing as you can see. I've been toying around with the various components of Bootstrap, and have managed to create an 'illustration'/example of an app that uses tooltips to interact with users. **This design is nested in a tab-toggle and is supposed to take half of the container col-md-6, but does not allow another col-md-6**. My design might be really bad, but I need to understand if its possible that the grid could be finally exhausted? And if not, what am I doing wrong?

I need to also note that the tab-toggle is not the main navbar. It's supposed to act as a separate container. 
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrA9H.jpg)
Please find my html below -

```html
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_a">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: #fff">
             <div class="section-heading">
               <h1 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s">Service Modelling</h1>
                  <p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                            SERVICE MODELLING AND RECOVERY TRANSACTIONING
                        </p>
             </div>

<div class="row service-parts">

       <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="center">
                <div class="block wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                    <img src="images/mycons/dbase.png" alt="img04" style="width: 120px" height="130px" />
                        <h4>SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT</h4>
                      <p>
                          Veritatis eligendi, dignissimos. Porta fermentum mus aute pulvinar earum minus platea massa feugiat rutrum urna facilisi ipsameum.
                      </p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="center">
          <div class="block wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="800ms">
              <img src="images/mycons/bar.png" alt="img04" style="width: 120px" height="130px" />
                  <h4>BUSINESS CONSULTING</h4>
                      <p>
                          Veritatis eligendi, dignissimos. Porta fermentum mus aute pulvinar earum minus platea massa feugiat rutrum urna facilisi ipsameum.
                      </p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="center">
          <div class="block wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="1s">
              <img src="images/mycons/clipb.png" alt="img04" style="width: 120px" height="130px" />
                  <h4>BUSINESS DEVELOPMENT</h4>
                      <p>
                          Veritatis eligendi, dignissimos. Porta fermentum mus aute pulvinar earum minus platea massa feugiat rutrum urna facilisi ipsameum.
                      </p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
        
</div>
              </div>

<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #428bca; ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="text-decoration-color: white">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#" style="color: #fff">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="popover" href="#" role="button" data-content="Keep track and model your business expenses. No more unreliable work sheets!" style="color: #fff">Expense Model
                            </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
                        </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="popover" href="#" role="button" data-content="Control your internal and external day to day services." style="color: #fff">Service Model</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="popover" href="#" role="button" data-content="Recover all your expenses before budget season ends!" style="color: #fff">Recoveries</a>
  </li>
</ul>
                    </div>
               </div>
       </div>
      </div>

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #428bca;">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content=".">
  Period
</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>       
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-2">
               <img src="images/about/grow.png" data-toggle="popover" role="button" data-content="Recover all your expenses before budget season ends!" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title">
               </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
<table class="table" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" data-trigger="focus" title="Something Nasty" role="button" data-content="View the periods in the break down that you want to see! SMART allows you to have full control of your finance.">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>Desc</th>
      <th>Entity A</th>
      <th>Entity B</th>
      <th>Global</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">This</th>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">That</th>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Things</th>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

               </div>
           </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default" style ="background-color: #428bca;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-left: -100px; color: #fff">Powered by - 
                    <img src="images/budgetworx.png" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title" style="width: 50px; margin-left: 370px; margin-top: -26px">
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
       </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab_b">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 20px">
      <div class="section-heading">
               <h1 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s">Expense Modelling</h1>
                  <p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                            SERVICE MODELLING AND RECOVERY TRANSACTIONING
                        </p>
                    </div>
              </div>
<!--This is the illustration start-->
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #428bca; ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="text-decoration-color: white">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#" style="color: #fff">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="popover" href="#" role="button" data-content="Keep track and model your business expenses. No more unreliable work sheets!" style="color: #fff">Expense Model
                            </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
                        </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="popover" href="#" role="button" data-content="Control your internal and external day to day services." style="color: #fff">Service Model</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="popover" href="#" role="button" data-content="Recover all your expenses before budget season ends!" style="color: #fff">Recoveries</a>
  </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
              </div>
       </div>
          </div>

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #428bca;">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content=".">
  Period
</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>       
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-2">
               <img src="images/about/grow.png" data-toggle="popover" role="button" data-content="Recover all your expenses before budget season ends!" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title">
               </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
<table class="table" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" data-trigger="focus" title="Something Nasty" role="button" data-content="View the periods in the break down that you want to see! SMART allows you to have full control of your finance.">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>Desc</th>
      <th>Entity A</th>
      <th>Entity B</th>
      <th>Global</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">This</th>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">That</th>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Things</th>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
      <td>xxxxx</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

               </div>
           </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default" style ="background-color: #428bca;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-left: -100px; color: #fff">Powered by - 
                    <img src="images/budgetworx.png" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title" style="width: 50px; margin-left: 370px; margin-top: -26px">
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!--This is the illustration end-->
       </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_d">
            <h4>Pane D</h4>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on left
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on bottom
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on right
</button>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_d1">
            <h4>Pane D1</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
                ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_d2">
            <h4>Pane D2</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
                ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[link is here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) Right now i can say no limit for nesting rows but plz go through link for more clarity..!!

To avoid horizontal scrolling try this

**code.css**

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hari I have tried adding col-md-6 next to it as it is in the same row. But the screen pulls the entire page to the left leaving a large amount of blank space.

Comment: soo..please tell me are you getting a horizontal scrollbar..?? and i will clarify you that max of 2 (col-md-6) you can use in a single row

Comment: Yes I am, not sure what the span is.

Comment: I think you are not using row [grid] system properly please reffer this link->http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp